# Curator Service discovery service not being found

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, service-discovery, apache-curator

I have two applications, one registering itself to the zookeeper service and the other trying to list the services that was registered.

However when I list them I am not finding any services

I am registering the service as follows

```
private ServiceDiscovery<InstanceDetails> getDiscovery() {
        return ServiceDiscoveryBuilder.builder(InstanceDetails.class)
            .basePath(Config.basePath)
            .client(curatorFramework)
            .serializer(jacksonInstanceSerializer)
            .build();
    }

public void advertiseAvailability() {
        try {
            ServiceDiscovery<InstanceDetails> discovery = getDiscovery();
            discovery.start();
            discovery.registerService(getInstance());
            discovery.close();
            System.out.println("Advertised");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw Throwables.propagate(e);
        }
    }
```

and when I try to obtain the service I have the following:

```
public Collection<ServiceInstance<InstanceDetails>> getWorkers(String serviceName) {
        Collection<ServiceInstance<InstanceDetails>> instances;

        try {
            instances = discovery.queryForInstances(serviceName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw Throwables.propagate(e);
        }

        return instances;
    }
```

Note that `discovery.queryForNames()` returns an array that contains my `serviceName` and "zookeeper"

Comment: Same problem - you're using ServiceDiscovery.close() incorrectly.

Comment: what do you mean by using ServiceDiscovery.close() incorrectly ? I'm basically having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I basically had the same issue. It pretty simple to resolve and pretty weird actually. So you can not actually close your **ServiceDiscovery** instance and it worked for me. But they should not give any result for discovery.queryForNames() in this case.